# How two determine that whether a function (equation) defines a 1-dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

For example, how will you determine that the equation like $x^2 - y^2 + x^4- y^4 = 0$ defines a 1-dimensional manifold or not? I'm new to the manifold theory and I'm pretty confused by its applications.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it by applying the regular level set theorem, also called the [pre-image theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_theorem). Write your equation in the form $F(x,y)=0$; in this example, $F(x,y)=x^2-y^2+x^4-y^4$. What you have to do is to verify the hypotheses of the regular level set theorem by proving that for each point $p=(x,y)$, if $p$ satisfies the equation then at least one of the two partial derivatives $\partial F/\partial x |_p$ or $\partial F / \partial y |_p$ is nonzero. Once you've done that, the conclusion of the regular level set theorem says that the solution set of the equation is a 1-manifold.

So for this example, assuming that $x^2-y^2+x^4-y^4=0$, prove that one of $2x+4x^3$ or $-2y-4y^3$ is nonzero.

Comment: Hi Lee, thank you so much for your explanation. In this case, in order to show that the equation defines a 1-dimensional manifold, I need to prove that at least one of the two partial derivatives is nonzero for all p satisfies the equation right? Since both of the partial derivatives are 0 when p = (0,0), then the equation doesn't define a 1-dimensional manifold, is it correct?

Comment: You need to show that $[f_x(p) \ f_y(p)] \not = \textbf{0}$ for all $p \in f^{-1}(0)$. To do this, you need to consider the set of points $(x,y)$ for which $2x+4x^3 = 0, -2y-4y^3 = 0$ and show $(x,y) \not \in f^{-1}(0)$.

Comment: You are right that about both partials equalling zero when $p=(0,0)$. But all you can conclude is that the pre-image theorem does not apply in this situation, so in the end it did not help. To prove something is *not* a 1-manifold is a different job.

Comment: can we simplify $F(x,y)=(x^2-y^2)(1+x^2+y^2)=0$ describing the same set as $|x|=|y|$?

Comment: That looks like a great idea!